# How can I remove an unstaged file without altering the repository?

Tags: git, github, gitkraken

I recently cloned a GitHub Repository to my computer (Windows 11 Dell). The cloning process went fine, but when I checked the status it shows two of the files were deleted and are waiting to commit the changes to the repository.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        deleted:    gfx/interface/goals/TRM_Army.png
        deleted:    gfx/interface/goals/TRM_Navy.png
```

The issue is here is that I cannot update this cloned repository as long as those files are present, and nothing I have tried has been able to remove them.

I've tried:

- Normal discard from GitKraken (my default program)
- `git reset`
- `git checkout`
- `git restore`
- Stashing the files
- `git clean`
- Deleting and re-cloning the repository
- Uninstalling and Reinstalling Git
- `git reflog`
- Case-Sensitivity
- `git rm`
- `git config`

All of these methods have failed to produce results. The best I've been able to do is unstage the files, but this is not helpful as I still cannot delete them. I have checked `git diff` but there are no differences that it can detect, only git status is detecting them. The error is being detected on four different programs: Git Bash, Git GUI, GitHub Desktop and GitKraken (though Git GUI and Git Bash don't show the errors anymore if they were unstaged). I am not able to commit the changes as it would delete the files from the repository, and I do not own nor do I have permission to alter the repository. Is there a way to remove these phantom deletions without altering the repository?

Git GUI is showing this:

```
deleted file mode 100644
Binary files a/gfx/interface/goals/TRM_Navy.png and /dev/null differ
```

TL;DR: I have phantom 'changes' that were not made but I cannot remove and I am not able to alter the repository in anyway from its' current condition. No solution that I have found so far has worked.

Comment: Technically, you can create a local commit which removes said files. If you want a way to protect yourself from accidentally pushing that commit, you can add a `pre-push` hook which makes sure that no commit you are pushing removes one of these files. Would that kind of solution work for you ?

Comment: also: can you please give more technical details about the issue you have ? how does the "git insists they've been altered but they really haven't" show up ? what is this "lack of modifications" that are applied to these files ?

Comment: LeGEC- Yes, it would help, but I have no idea how to make a local commit period, let alone with a pre-push hook. As for the questions: The git is showing two png files in the unstaged/staged area. They've not been altered from the files already in the repository, but they are there for some reason. From what I can tell there's no difference, but the git will not let me discard them.

Comment: There could be two paths committed in git which differ only in uppercase/lowercase characters. Here is a command to inspect the content of the active commit in the repo : `git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD | grep -i TRM_Navy.png`. Does this command show 2 lines or more ?

Comment: Yes. It’s showing two goal files with the same name, just different cases, same for the TRM_army.png

Comment: Closer examination of the Repository shows the same thing. Exact same files duplicated with the same path, just different cases. Likely the culprit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue appears to be on the repository's end, as it looks like the repository has duplicated the problematic files, with two copies of each one, varying only by case. I've messaged the repository about the glitched files, so hopefully they'll fix it at some point.

Answer (score 1):

From our exchange in the comments: the weird behavior you see is linked to a case sensitivity issue.

Two files, which differ only in casing, are stored in git, and you are checking out this content on a case insensitive filesystem. So only one of these two files exist on disk, and git thinks the other one is deleted.

---

The longterm fix is to fix the issue in the repository itself: avoid having two paths which differ only in casing stored in git -- it probably is a bug to start with.

In order to ease working with a case insensitive filesystem (such as NTFS) on a git repository, you can turn on the [`core.ignoreCase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreignoreCase) option in git:

```
# to turn it on for that repo only:
git config core.ignoreCase true

# to turn it on for all your repos on this machine:
git config --global core.ignoreCase true
```

If this central repository is mainly used by Windows users, you could also spread the word that other users should turn this option on on their side.

Answer (score 0):

If you are removing files from a tracked directory, you are creating a change to the repository that needs to be committed.

Weren't these files at some point added to your repository and committed?

In any case, if you wish to stop tracking files at any point (which includes removing them locally without committing the change), you simply need to use the untrack feature in Git.

```
git rm --cached myfile.txt
git update-index --assume-unchanged myfile.txt
git status
```

The first command will delete the file. The second instructs Git to ignore the change to the local file catalog. Finally, a look at the status should indicate no uncommitted changes.

Be warned though: while this works, there are only a few real-world scenarios where you would actually want to do this. It's time to rethink your working practices.

I use this procedure to add or change config files when working on public projects where I don't want to push commits containing secrets.